# How to get embed content from a deleted message?

Tags: python, discord.py, embed, message

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_message_delete(self, payload):
        try:
            conn.reconnect()
        except:
            pass
        print("deleted")
        channel=self.client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message=await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) #<===========
        emb=message.embeds
        for mes in emb:
            cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM suggestions WHERE channel_id={payload.channel_id} and id={payload.guild_id} and code={mes.fields[1].value}")
            conn.commit()
```

discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code:10008): Unknown message

When I changed the code to this, it showed me the another error

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_message_delete(self, payload):
        try:
            conn.reconnect()
        except:
            pass
        print("deleted")
        channel=self.client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message=payload.cached_message
        emb=message.embeds  #<===========
        for mes in emb:
            cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM suggestions WHERE channel_id={payload.channel_id} and id={payload.guild_id} and code={mes.fields[1].value}")
            conn.commit()
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'embeds'

How I can get a content from embeds?

Comment: I think the error speaks for itself, you cannot fetch a message  that doesn't exist

Comment: And how to get content from a message(embeds) that doesn't exist?

Comment: If my comment before wasn't obvious enough, you can't. Unless it's cached by the bot

Answer (score 1):

If you want the embed from the message, you can use the `on_message_delete` event, since it gives you the message object, like this:

```py
async def on_message_delete(message): # Event that triggers every time a message is deleted
    try:
        conn.reconnect()
    except:
        pass
    print("Deleted")
    emb = message.embeds
    for mes in emb:
        cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM suggestions WHERE channel_id={message.channel.id} and id={message.guild.id} and code={mes.fields[1].value}")
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: Then I can't get a content from old messages after restart